# Compare each month and add rows for deltas

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, compare

I need your help I can't build right solution.

I have this table:

| Date | Unit | Currency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.02.2021 | TSS | USD |
| 01.03.2021 | TSS | USD |
| 01.04.2021 | TSS | USD |
| 01.02.2021 | UMM | USD |
| 01.02.2021 | FDS | USD |
| 01.04.2021 | FDS | USD |
| 01.02.2021 | POF | USD |

I need to populate rows for each missing UNIT for each month like UNIT "TSS" comparing with the first month 01.02.2021 .

Expected result:

| Date | Unit | Currency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.02.2021 | TSS | USD |
| 01.03.2021 | TSS | USD |
| 01.04.2021 | TSS | USD |
| 01.02.2021 | UMM | USD |
| 01.03.2021 | UMM | USD |
| 01.04.2021 | UMM | USD |
| 01.02.2021 | FDS | USD |
| 01.03.2021 | FDS | USD |
| 01.04.2021 | FDS | USD |
| 01.02.2021 | POF | USD |
| 01.03.2021 | POF | USD |
| 01.04.2021 | POF | USD |

All comparisons should be with the first month 01.02.2021

Comment: One method is a cross join. Get all distinct values of Unit and cross join that with all distinct values of date and add "USD" as a constant. But I will guess that your situation will require more complexity.

Comment: Can you add your table schema and data scripts to support you to get the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Your results have all combinations of the first column `date` with all combinations of the other two `unit`/`currency`.  Use `cross join`:

```
select d.date, uc.unit, uc.currency
from (select distinct date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct unit, currency from t) uc
order by uc.unit, uc.currency, d.date;
```